# TypeError: function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested-function

I want the greet function to say "Hi Sam, Hi Cody" using the format function but I am getting this error:

```
greet(names())
TypeError: greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' 



def names():
        def name1():
            x = "Sam"
            return x
        def name2():
            y = "Cody"
            return y
```

What do I need to put in greet(names()) to get this to work?

```
from names import names

def greet(x,y):
    template = "Hi {}, Hi {} ".format(x,y)
    print(template)


greet(names())
```

Comment: You are only returning a single value at a time

Comment: Is there a way I can return both of the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after:

```
def name1():
    return 'Sam'

def name2():
    return 'Cody'

def greet (x, y):
    print (f'Hi {x}, Hi {y}')
    
greet (name1(), name2())

# Result:
    # Hi Sam, Hi Cody
```

**names() returning multiple outputs**

If you wanted to write a single function `names()` that returns multiple outputs, you can do it like this:

```
def names():
    return 'Sam', 'Cody'
```

The return from `names()` is a `tuple` containing two strings. If you pass it directly to `greet()`, you'll be passing `greet()` a single argument - a `tuple` that happens to contain two things within it. That will produce the error you were getting:

```
greet (names())

TypeError: greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

You could, on the other hand, unpack the `tuple` returned by `names()` when you pass it to `greet()`, like so:

```
greet (*names())
# Result:
    # Hi Sam, Hi Cody
```

Comment: Yeah I realized that def names was serving no purpose and that a function can only return one thing at a time so I just took it out. Thanks for the help. I am new.

Comment: No worries. Functions can actually return lots of things at once. I'll update the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Wow, that explanation made everything work, this was a dumbed down version of what I'm trying to accomplish in another program and you, my friend, just made it all come together. If I had enough points to upvote, I would, but it won't let me LOL.

Comment: No sweat, just accept the answer to close out the question. Good luck to you.